# Parents not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div id="comentario-info">
  <b>AngelRmz</b> hace 8 minutos
  <div id="comentario-botones" data-id="1">
    <div id="comentario-boton"  class="comentario-informar" title="Informar"></div>
    <div id="comentario-boton"  class="comentario-eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div>
    <div id="comentario-boton"  class="comentario-editar" title="Editar"></div>
    <div id="comentario-boton"  class="comentario-guardar" title="Guardar"></div>
  </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
comentarioId = $(this).parents().parent('#comentario-botones').attr("data-id");
alert(comentarioId); // return 1
```

Comment: `id` of element within `document` should be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `parent()` when you already use `.parents()`,

`parents()` will give you all parents elements u can simple pass its ID, Class or Attr,

Also ID must be unique.

In case you don't want to make ID unique and still want to use ID selector, I have simple solution for that.

Your ID selector must be like this `$('[id="your-ID"]')`

```js
$('[id="comentario-boton"]').click(function(){
  comentarioId = $(this).parents('#comentario-botones').attr("data-id");
  alert(comentarioId);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="comentario-info">
<b>AngelRmz</b> hace 8 minutos
<div id="comentario-botones" data-id="1">
  <div id="comentario-boton" class="comentario-informar" title="Informar">Informar</div>
  <div id="comentario-boton" class="comentario-eliminar" title="Eliminar">Eliminar</div>
  <div id="comentario-boton" class="comentario-editar" title="Editar">Editar</div>
  <div id="comentario-boton" class="comentario-guardar" title="Guardar">Guardar</div>
</div>
```

Note: This is not a good practice but this is simple hack for developer who want to use same ID for a reason.

Comment: Woow! :O   its code beautiful !! You have solved all my problems

Answer (score 3):

Id must be unique. You use `data-id`. So fetch the value use `data` .

```js
 $("#comentario-botones").on("click", "div", function() {
  var comentarioId = $(this).parent().data('id');;
  alert(comentarioId); // return 1
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="comentario-info">
  <b>AngelRmz</b> hace 8 minutos
  <div id="comentario-botones" data-id="1">
    <div id="comentario-boton1" class="comentario-informar" title="Informar">1</div>
    <div id="comentario-boton2" class="comentario-eliminar" title="Eliminar">2</div>
    <div id="comentario-boton3" class="comentario-editar" title="Editar">3</div>
    <div id="comentario-boton4" class="comentario-guardar" title="Guardar">4</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Would be much more efficient to do ***$("#comentario-botones").on("click", "div", function()***... That way you only need to attach single eventhandler instead of adding it to every child div.

Comment: instead of `parents()` use `parent()`